# Random white box on my website in internet explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, web

i am developping a website for house selling, and on the jquery script in using (Gallerific), there is a random white box appearing on the right side of the page only in INTERNET EXPLORER. For all other browser, it works perfectly.
You can see it if  you try to select the text that should be right under the main house image.

Now, i am wondering why such a thing appear and how to solve it.

you can take a look at what result i have :
http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/5921/wierdbox.jpg

and here is the link to the page:
http://www.constructionneuvegatineau.com/maisons.html

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

C'est facile.

Set the CSS for that block of text:

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Comment: The thing is i did that. I added : background-color:transparent !important;
at many places in hope of getting this white area lifted. You can see it at lines 308,294 and 255 of my css code :S